# C# "InvalidCastException" when trying to access webbrowser control from TimerCallback

Tags: c#, browser

Basically I have the same problem as this user: 
[How to check for TrackBar sliding with mouse hold and release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717934/how-to-check-for-trackbar-sliding-with-mouse-hold-and-release)
I fixed this using the first solution provided. However, when the timer is called, I want to call InvokeScript on a webbrowser control. InvokeScript runs without an error, but the javascript function is never called. When I call this script from like a button clicked event handler, the function is called properly.

I found out that when I try to access properties from the webbrowser control (like MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.DocumentText), this throws a InvalidCastException.

```
// in constructor:
webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
webBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(this.TimerElapsed);     

private void trackBar2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        timer.Change(500, -1);
}
private void TimerElapsed(object state)
{
    this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("jmp_end");
    MessageBox.Show(this.webBrowser1.DocumentText);
    timerRunning = false;
}
private void TimerElapsed(object state)
{
    WebBrowser brw = getBrowser();
    brw.Document.InvokeScript("jmpend");
    MessageBox.Show(brw.DocumentText);
    timerRunning = false;
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Or is there another way to get the same result?

After comments about InvokeRequired, this sounds exactly like what I need.. But I can't get it working.. This is what I made from the sample code from [C# System.InvalidCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268281/c-sharp-system-invalidcastexception)

```
public delegate WebBrowser getBrowserHandler();
public WebBrowser getBrowser()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        return Invoke(new getBrowserHandler(getBrowser)) as WebBrowser;
    }
    else
    {
        return webBrowser1;
    }
}

private void TimerElapsed(object state)
{
    WebBrowser brw = getBrowser();
    brw.Document.InvokeScript("jmpend");
    MessageBox.Show(brw.DocumentText);
    timerRunning = false;
}
```

What have I missed here?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268281/c-sharp-system-invalidcastexception

Comment: Use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer to avoid challenging IE to provide properties in a thread safe way.

Comment: I added some code to clarify my question. I'm sorry for being unclear. Hope someone sees what I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you place your Timer on the windows form in the Visual Studio designer? Read the 'Remarks' carefully here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx -- Also, you are stopping the timer in your event handler. You might want to use `AutoReset = false` instead in your timer setup.

Comment: No, it is a System.Threading.Timer, which doesn't have a AutoReset property. And timerRunning is a boolean, technically not related to the Timer itself.

Answer (score 6):

The caller (the timer) is on a different thread than the control was created on.

See [Control.InvokeRequired Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx)

Sample code that should address your issue is posted on this question: [C# System.InvalidCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268281/c-sharp-system-invalidcastexception)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. As pointed out by Kevin P. Rice, the caller is on a diferente thread than the one the control was created on. A simple solution for this is to use `this.Invoke()` everytime the thread needs to interact with a control, therefore, if you desire to have the browser invoke a script, and you wish to call it from inside a separate thread, just do it like this:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => { brw.Document.InvokeScript("jmpend"); }));
```

Or if you wish to change the property of the browse or another control within the form:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => { button1.Enabled = false; }));
```

If the declaration of your thread is in another scope than that of your form, and you can't use the `this` keyword, you need to find a way to reference the current instance of the form.

I hope this helps. :)