# BackgroundWorker and webBrowser - specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code:

```
void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            var table = webBrowser3.Document.GetElementById("emailTable");
            var tr = table.GetElementsByTagName("tr");
            if (tr.Count > 1)
            {
                var link = tr[1].GetElementsByTagName("td")[1].GetElementsByTagName("a")[0].GetAttribute("href");
                webBrowser3.Navigate(link);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //webBrowser3.Document.GetElementById("emailTable"); => Specified cast is not valid        
        }  
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

In my code, I am loading a webpage in `webBrowser3` inside of my winform app, and then I am starting `backgroundWorker1` in order to catch any changes made to a site (site adds a  element to a table via ajax). Unfortunately, it throws an exception.

How can I periodically check `webBrowser3.Document` for changes, and allow winform app to work continuously?

Comment: What is the exact stack trace of the exception and the full exception message?

Comment: And what is `webBrowser3`?

Comment: And how are you attempting to determine if there's changes to the page? Are you storing the elements/values in a db so you have something to compare to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# "InvalidCastException" when trying to access webbrowser control from TimerCallback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048922/c-sharp-invalidcastexception-when-trying-to-access-webbrowser-control-from-tim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the `UI Controls` from the `Non-UI` Thread `BackgroundWorker`.
You can use `InvokeRequired`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    Gets a value indicating whether the caller must call an invoke method when 
making method calls to the control because the caller is on a different 
thread than the one the control was created on.
```

Try This:

```
    if(this.webBrowser3.InvokeRequired)
    {
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {
                var table = webBrowser3.Document.GetElementById("emailTable");
                var tr = table.GetElementsByTagName("tr");
                if (tr.Count > 1)
                {
                    var link = tr[1].GetElementsByTagName("td")[1].GetElementsByTagName("a")[0].GetAttribute("href");
                    webBrowser3.Navigate(link);
                }                    
         });
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that exception because you can't access GUI controls from a background worker; the background worker is on a different thread by defintion.

If you want to do something like this, you'll need to instead make a call to that website from the background worker, perhaps using [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) and compare that with what you already have.